# Eclipse indigo for Mac OS Maven problems

Tags: maven, osx-lion

Did anybody try to install Eclipse Indigo EE on Mac OS Lion? My Windows Machine died and I had to install Eclipse 3.7 on my Mac OS Lion. I updated Eclipse with Maven. And for 2 days I could not figure out why Maven was not getting archetypes beyond the regular archetypes that seemed to be packaged with it. Like 'org.broadleafcommerce'.

I found a way around it by adding a remote repository:http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml. I never needed to add this in a windows install.

So, I was able to create a webapp project using the 'maven-archetype-webapp'. But now it would not add dependencies, like spring.
The version is Eclipse java IDE for web developers, Indigo Service Release 2, Build id: 20120216-1057.

Is there a better even if older version of Eclipse? Note, I have tried downloading Maven and updating Eclipse installations in preferences - which did not work. And also, I am not behind a firewall since I am at home. I have been googling for 3 sleepless days now.

Thanks.